# Anchor out of my modal box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link in my modal box that have to goes to an anchor.

**What I would like :** When the user click on the link (`<a data-dismiss="modal" href="#video-tuto" class="jaune" >consulter nos tutos</a>`), the modal box closed and the page scroll to the anchor.

**What I have :** When I click on the link, the modal box closes but there is no scroll ...

I'm working with Bootstrap 3.

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-dalle-exterieure" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <!-- Bouton fermer (croix) -->
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title uppercase" id="myModalLabel">Dalle extérieure</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>Et pour des conseils de réalisation étape par étape, n’hésitez pas à
                        <a data-dismiss="modal" href="#video-tuto" class="jaune" >consulter nos tutos</a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the page with the anchor :

```
<div id="video-tuto" class="row video-tuto letterspacing">
    <div class="col-lg-12 titre">
        <h3 class="uppercase">vidéos tutos ...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may listen for [hidden.bs.modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

In order to scroll to your div you can use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```js
$('#modal-dalle-exterieure').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#video-tuto").offset().top},
          'fast');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-dalle-exterieure">
    Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-dalle-exterieure" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- Bouton fermer (croix) -->
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title uppercase" id="myModalLabel">Dalle extérieure</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>Et pour des conseils de réalisation étape par étape, n’hésitez pas à
                    <a data-dismiss="modal" href="#video-tuto" class="jaune" >consulter nos tutos</a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 300px;">

</div>

<div id="video-tuto" class="row video-tuto letterspacing">
    <div class="col-lg-12 titre">
        <h3 class="uppercase">vidéos tutos ...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```